# How to send buttons in webhooks in discord.js@13.6.0 and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord.js, webhooks

So, I am trying to send an embed and two buttons in a webhook from my website backend which is built using express.js to Discord using discord.js. So, here is my source code:-

```js
const buttons = new MessageActionRow()

buttons.addComponents(
    new MessageButton()
        .setLabel('View Purchase')
        .setStyle('LINK')
        .setURL(`...`), // url is present
)

buttons.addComponents(
    new MessageButton()
        .setLabel('View Payment')
        .setStyle('LINK')
        .setURL(`...`), // url is present
)

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
// creating the embed

await webhook.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [buttons] })
```

I have removed unnecessary code. So if I run this, the embed gets sent, but not the buttons and there is no error except some warning which are unrelated.

```
(node:13492) DeprecationWarning: Passing strings for MessageEmbed#setFooter is deprecated. Pass a sole object instead.
[0] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Comment: Basically, the deprecation warning is saying that you can no longer do `embed.setFooter('footer txt')`. You must now do `embed.setFooter({ text: 'footer text' })` instead. I'm not sure why the buttons aren't being sent, although to clean things up, you can add multiple components in the `buttons.addComponents`. Just separate them with commas.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Discord Docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook-jsonform-params) the Webhook has to be owned by an application wich means your discord bot have to create the webhook first in order to add buttons to the webhook (this counts for every other message component too).

Answer (score -1):

change .setFooter to this style :
`.setFooter({text: "your text", iconURL: "your link"`

Comment: That is not the issue :( My problem was with the buttons not being sent...